# Observable me devuelve un subscriber y no el objeto

Tags: angular

lo que pasa es que en mi proyecto estoy tratando de que el servicio me devuelva el objeto en base al index que le pase, pero en lugar de devolverme el objeto con la información me devuelve un subscriber, ya he intentado varias cosas pero no logro que funcione, soy nueva en Angular y esto me está retrasando un poco, ¿podrían ayudarme a corregir mi código por favor?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ParableService {
  public urlParables: any;
  public parable: any;

  constructor( private _httpClient: HttpClient) { 
    this.urlParables = 'http://localhost:3000/parabolas';
    this.parable = {};
  }

  setParables(): Observable<any>{

    return this._httpClient.get(`${this.urlParables}`);
  }

  getIdParable(index:number){
      return this.setParables().subscribe(data => {
        this.parable = data[index];
        console.log(this.parable)
      })
  }

//ESTE ES EL SERVICIO
}

//ESTE EL COMPONENTE

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Parable } from '../../interface/parable';
import { ParableService } from '../../services/parable.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parable',
  templateUrl: './parable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parable.component.scss']
})
export class ParableComponent implements OnInit {
  public parable:any;

  constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _parableService: ParableService
  ) {
    this.parable = {};
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    this.parable = this._parableService.getIdParable(params.index);
    console.log(this.parable);
  });
  }



}
```

Y esto es lo que arroja la consola sobre el componente

Subscriber {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}closed: truedestination: SafeSubscriber {closed: true, *parentOrParents: null, *subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}isStopped: truesyncErrorThrowable: truesyncErrorThrown: falsesyncErrorValue: null_parentOrParents: null_subscriptions: null__proto**: Subscription

Answer (score 0):

Debes de acceder al flujo con `pipe` y `map` de esta manera:

```
 setParables(index:number): Observable<any>{

    return this._httpClient.get(`${this.urlParables}`)
    .pipe(map( (respuesta: any)=>{
     return respuesta[index]
     }, 
          catchError(error=> throwError(error));
  }
```

La importación de `map` es desde `rxjs`.